# Last Access Time Update in Hive metastore

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following property in my Hive console/ `.hiverc` file, so that whenever I query the table, it updates the `LAST_ACCESS_TIME` column in `TBLS` table of Hive metastore.

```sql
set hive.exec.pre.hooks = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook$PreExec;
```

However, if I use `spark-sql` or `spark-shell`, it does not seems to be working and `LAST_ACCESS_TIME` does not gets updated in hive metastore.

Here's how I am reading the table :

```scala
>>> df = spark.sql("select * from db.sometable")
>>> df.show()
```

I have set up the above hook in `hive-site.xml` in both `/etc/hive/conf` and `/etc/spark/conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may skip past some of the hive integrations. My recollection is that to get more of the Hive-ish integrations you need to bring in the HiveContext, something like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, HiveContext

if __name__ == "__main__":

  # create Spark context with Spark configuration
  conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Data Frame Join")
  sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
  sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
  df_07 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from sample_07")
```

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.7/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-sql-example.html

Hope this helps